# Replace for-loop across week with list comprehension

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

How do I replace the following `for` loops with a more efficient list comprehension or something similar? `Numpy` and `Pandas` are not an option as they are not installed on the client system, but perhaps `itertools` could be useful?

```
n_day_cells      = 24*60/240
week_matrix      = list()

for i in range(7):
    for j in range(n_day_cells):
        week_matrix.append([i,j,0])
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I should perhaps have been a bit more specific. I'm on Python 2.7 with no other packages than the "core" packages such as `itertools`. This code needs to run ~1M-1B times in my script.

Comment: List comprehension are more concise, but they aren't more efficient than basic for loops. BTW, it's better to do `week_matrix = []` rather than `week_matrix = list()`.

Comment: That's not a strict answer, but you can use `itertools.product`: `list(itertools.product(range(7), range(n_day_cells), range(1)))`

Comment: Does the order of the items in ```week_matrix``` matter?

Comment: Yes, that is crucial.

Comment: what is the actually size of the list you are creating? Also do you have cython installed?

Comment: I think `7*6=42` loop cycles isn't essential to optimize.

Comment: Your solution compares favorably with the others posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using:

```
week_matrix = [[i,j,0] for i in range(7) for j in range(n_day_cells)]
```

In case your ranges are bigger and you are on Python2, you might want to use `xrange` instead of `range` to get an iterator.

---

If you are really bent on saving more time, use xrange, and create a list of tuples instead of list of lists (all examples in Python2):

```
In [3]: %timeit [[i,j,0] for i in range(7) for j in range(n_day_cells)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.51 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit [(i,j,0) for i in range(7) for j in range(n_day_cells)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.6 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit [(i,j,0) for i in xrange(7) for j in xrange(n_day_cells)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.09 µs per loop
```

The last one above should be the fastest alternative even if you want to use it as a generator:

```
week_matrix = ((i,j,0) for i in xrange(7) for j in xrange(n_day_cells))
```

---

The other answer provided with map, though interesting, will have more overhead because of the repetitive calls to the `lambda` and call to `map`:

```
In [6]: %timeit map(lambda x: [x//6, x%6, 0], xrange(n_day_cells*7))
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: If it's Python 2. If it's Python 3, there's no `xrange`, so definitely go with `range` then. (It's efficient like `xrange`)

Comment: How is the generator the fastest?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It should be fastest if the OP is ok using  generators. Depending on the requirement, he may not want to use generator and may need a pre built list instead.

Comment: How does it compare to OPs solution?

Comment: @wwii Didn't time that, but OP's solution should be slower because of the repetitve `.append` calls.

Answer (score 1):

Build list by using `map`.

```
n_day_cells = 24*60/240
map(lambda x: [x//n_day_cells, x%n_day_cells, 0], xrange(n_day_cells*7))
```

Or one way using `itertools`.

```
import itertools
a = itertools.imap(lambda x: [x//n_day_cells, x%n_day_cells, 0], xrange(n_day_cells*7))
```

The time will be consumed when the values are needed. No noticeable memory will be consumed.

Comment: To be equivalent, the lambda shouldn't have the ```6``` *hard coded*. If ```n_day_cells``` changes, this won't work.